# How to customizing a table view cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to customize table view cells in the `cellFotRowAtIndexPath` method, but the styles are not being applied.

[image]

Am I putting the code in the wrong spot?

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.buttonTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 Die", @"2 Dice", @"3 Dice", @"4 Dice", @"5 Dice", @"6 Dice", @"7 Dice", @"8 Dice", @"Roll with a Button", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return buttonTitles.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"settingsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:14];

    NSString *titles = [self.buttonTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = titles;
    cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return cell;
}
```

### Update:

In the view debugger there are empty cells:

[image]

Comment: Is the view controller a subclass of UITableViewController or UIViewController?

Comment: @Avi, it is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: try to change the type of the cell to "Custom" on your storyBoard. Don't know if you can change a "Basic" cell type,  or other predifined styles,  attributes.

Comment: That's what an empty tableView looks like.  Put a breakpoint in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, or add a log, to see how many rows are being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

```
return buttonTitles.count;
```

That is referencing an instance variable named buttonTitles, and not the property you assign in `viewDidLoad`.  Change the line to read

```
return self.buttonTitles.count;
```

You can also remove the declaration of the `buttonTitles` instance variable.  You probably don't need it.

Comment: Are any cells at all displayed?  If you check in the view debugger, do you see cells?  It's hard to tell from your screenshot if the tableView is even visible at all.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the delegates. `self.tableview.delegate=self;` `self.tableView.dataSource = self;`

Comment: @gomezluisj, were would this code go? `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: None of the cells are showing. Just a blank table view controller.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Add the code in viewDidLoad, don't forget to use the tableview name you set.

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the delegate for tableview
The following code will work

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.buttonTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 Die", @"2 Dice", @"3 Dice", @"4 Dice", @"5 Dice", @"6 Dice", @"7 Dice", @"8 Dice", @"Roll with a Button", nil];
    UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
}

 -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return buttonTitles.count;
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"settingsCell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"settingsCell"];
    }




 // Configure the cell...
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:14];

    NSString *titles = [self.buttonTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = titles;
    cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;

these two lines are the main by which the delegate gets called.

But for the delegate to be called you have to declare the <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> delegates

Comment: Nothing so far. I added the delegates in the `@interface` of the `.m` file. IS that correct?                                                                                                                                                                                              
`@interface SettingsTableViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> `

Comment: you can add it anywhere either in the .h file or .m file.Is it working now?

Comment: No, it looks the same.

Comment: Did you alloc init this view controller somewhere else? Have you tried keeping breakpoint in viewDidLoad in this view controller and does the control come there?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding, but I can say that I have not allocated and initialized the view controller anywhere else.

Comment: Try adding this line to your ViewController 

   `TableViewController table = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:table.view];`

Comment: Add that line to your Viewcontroller or the file from which you want to call your TableViewController

Comment: I tried to put it in the prepareForSegue method and that didn't work, so I tried the viewDidLoad and when I tried to run the project and and got an internal issue error, so I'll have to try again.

Comment: I tried and I didn't notice a difference. Xcode did tell me to change your code to `UITableViewController *table = [[UITableViewController alloc]init]; [self.view addSubview:table.view];`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell and in attributes inspector from IB, change TableView Style to Custom